# Create a column with Conditional Recursive SQL / based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the table ordered by **id** with column **IsSatisfied**.

| ID | IsSatisfied |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 |
| .... | ... |

I would like to create another column **State**, that initially takes value 0 and changes it between 0 and 1, only when the value of **Isatisfied** is equal to 1, as in the table below.

| ID | IsSatisfied | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 |
| .... | ... | ... |

I tried LAG() function or recursive CTE, but unfortunately failed.
The closest solution that I have found is [Conditional Recursive SQL Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139648/conditional-recursive-sql-select), but I was not able to convert it to suit my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative sum of `issatisfied` -- and then the remainder when divided by 2:

```
select t.*,
       ( sum(issatisfied) over (order by id) % 2 ) as state
from t;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!